# Problem with caption in \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a problem with `\listoftables` command.

`\listoftables` gets data from `\captions` and displays it in the table list. Is it possible for `\listoftables` to retrieve text from another command?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Very long caption.} \label{tab:sometab}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Hi & I \\
Need & Help \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In `\listoftables` I don't want "Very long caption" but I want to have something else, for example: "Short caption".

Comment: Because I write my master thesis and very long caption in \listoftables looks very ugly and I want to shorten it but i don't want interfere in caption in table.

Comment: Have you tried `\caption[short caption]{Very long caption.}`?

Comment: It's working. Thanks. But do you know how can I remove subcaption from \listoftables?

Comment: Please ask a new question about subcaption and add an MWE showing the issue you get ant want to solve.

Comment: One can also add text to the LOT using `\addtocontents{lot}{text}`.  This is used, for example, to add extra space between chapters.

Comment: Oh.I am so sorry. I did that alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add option `[short caption]` to your used `\caption` command.

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\listoftables % <=======================================================

\begin{table}
\caption[short caption]{Very long caption.} \label{tab:sometab} % <=====
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Hi & I \\
Need & Help \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]